# How can I quickly load images without using lazy load?

Tags: performance, image, load

I am a photographer and I recently revamped my website to a one page layout to display my portfolio. I have used HTML/CSS/Jquery to build the site. In the current format I have used the page scroll function to navigate from one section to another. While this is working out to be great, the page takes forever to load. I did some research and learnt about lazy loader and its likes but the problem is that I am not fluent with CSS or Jquery. I am okay with HTML. I usually take some examples and tweek them as per my requirements. Due to this constraint, I am not able to implement lazy loader. Is there an easier way to do this?

Moreover, I would really like to load the images quickly, instead of load-when-needed, because if the user jumps from one section to another, I would like the images to be visibile during the automatic scrolling.

This is my website - http://www.thekite.in

Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd remove the loading animation as it actually makes the visitor wait longer before they can see anything.

Do you really need all the javascript you have on the page? If so you should merge the files and move the scripts that can be moved to the bottom of the page.

You've got a 166 resources on the page that weigh in at 22MB all together.

Optimise the images the page is just too big (something like jpegmini.com is really useful for this)

A browser can only open a limited number of connections at the same time (6 for most modern browsers), so you should shard the images across multiple domains e.g. http://images1..., http://images2 etc.

Other thing you could do it lazy load them depending on what's visible but I'd start with the above first.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I'll see how I can clear up the javascript. 

Can you elaborate on "sharding" the images across domains? I didn't understand.

Comment: Serve images from several sub-domains e.g. http://images1.domain.com, http://images2.domain.com etc. Have a read of this - http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#ParallelizeDownloads

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I've got it sorted out now. Did a combination of sharding the images, jpegmini and lazyload.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search brought me to that: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Since you are using jquery this lazy loader might be an option...

You should also consider client side (browser) caching of your images. When your webserver adds the right HTTP cache header to your images, the browsers don't have to load them multiple times.

To check where your performance bottlenecks are, check out YSlow: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

It is a browser plugin that helps to improve the performance of your website.

Comment: Thanks for the response, mohlendo. I did go through the jQuery link that you gave but it was said, in a different forum, that it was not supported anymore. Hence, I tried using a different version.

I googled client side caching of images - I only get ASP.Net solutions. Is there I can adapt this since I am using HTML, CSS and Jquery?

I went through the yslow results. Unfortunately only little of the critical errors (highlighted in red) made any sense to me. Thanks for the suggestion, though.